# Hibernate через criteria возвращает несколько копий объектов

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Доброго времени суток.
Недавно начал изучать Hibernate и столкнулся с проблемой.
У Меня есть 2 таблицы, со связью много ко многим(Таблицы "Документ" и "Авторы", т.е у одного документа много авторов и наоборот). На данный момент в бд есть 1 документ у которого 3 автора. При попытке получить все документы(через criteria), Я получаю не 1 объект, а 3 его копии. В чем проблема, не понимаю.

Класс для документов:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;
@Column(name = "last_unit_mod")
private int unit;
@Column(name = "last_time_mod")
private Date lastTimeUpdate;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "keywords")
private String keywords;
@Column(name="language")
private String language;
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "documents_to_author",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
private Set<Author> authors;
```

Класс для авторов:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;
@Column(name = "last_unit_mod")
private int unit;
@Column(name = "last_date_mod")
private Date lastTimeUpdate;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "documents_to_author",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id"))
private List<Document> documents;
```

И собственно вот так пытаюсь получить все документы:

```
public static List<Document> findAll(){
    List<Document> result = session.createCriteria(Document.class).list();
    return result;
}
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: а эти документы идентичны?

Comment: Да, он возвращает List с 3 одинаковыми документами. Если их сравнивать через стандартный equals, то возвращает true. Т.е. он 3 раза один и тот же объект добавляет в List

Comment: Попробуй ManyToMany комментировать  и пробуй получить

Comment: Так то он вернет как положено 1 объект, тут проблема как раз в связи, а где именно, понять не могу.

Comment: Вообщем, немного поигравшись с настройками, понял, что это происходило из-за FetchType.EAGER у таблицы. Убрав это (или сменив на FetchType.LAZY), стало вытягивать по 1 копии объектов.

Comment: оформи как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, немного поигравшись с настройками, понял, что это происходило из-за FetchType.EAGER у таблицы. Убрав это (или сменив на FetchType.LAZY), стало вытягивать по 1 копии объектов.